# Error 404 when trying to run PHP insert file in html

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fairly new to MVC coding, and I am trying to write a simple web application that can store my members information. I have a html form that I want to call another file named "insertmember.php", and the "insertmember.php" is supposed to take the parameter passed in from the form and insert into my mysql database. The problem is I am not sure if I placed the "insertmember.php" in a wrong location, or if there is some other setting I missed in order for the page to get pulled up..

Everything (Apache Server and MySQL) is running XAMPP
My "insertmember.php" file is currently placed in 
E:\xampp\htdocs\Firstwebapp\application\views

My PHP file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    function index()
    {

        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "test";

        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn->connect_error) 
        {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 

        $sql = "SELECT member_ID, member_name, city_level, attack_power FROM member";
        //$result = $conn->query($sql);
        $data['result'] = $conn->query($sql);   
        $data['title'] = "GreenForest Member";
        $data['heading'] = "List of GreenForest members:";

        $this->load->view('home', $data);

        $conn->close();     


    }

}
?>
```

My HTML file

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
<?=$title?>
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Add New member</h3>
    <form action = "insertmember.php" method ="post"> 
        member_name  : <input type = "text" name = "member_name">
        <br/>
        city_level   : <input type = "text" name = "city_level">
        <br/>
        attack_power : <input type = "text" name = "attack_power">
        <br/>
        <input type =  "submit" value = "INSERT">
    </form>
<h3><?=$heading?></h3>

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>Member_ID</th>
        <th>Member_name</th>
        <th>City_level</th>
        <th>Attack_power</th>
    </tr>
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo$row['member_ID'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo$row['member_name'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo$row['city_level'] ?></th>
        <th><?php echo$row['attack_power'] ?></th>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

My insertmember.php file

```
<html>
<body>

<? php

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "test";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $member_name = $_POST['member_name'];
    $city_level = $_POST['city_level'];
    $attack_power = $_POST['attack_power']; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO member (member_name, city_level, attack_power) VALUES ( '$member_name', '$city_level', '$attack_power')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql))
    {
        echo 'not inserted';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'inserted';
    }

    mysql_close($con)

    header("refresh:2; url=index.html");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I expect that when I click the button "INSERT" on my index page, the value in the form will go into the database, and page will be refreshed to show the new record

[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01l34.png)

Comment: Maybe this is not the problem because you are running in Windows, but I suggest you to be consistent in the capitalization of the file names. You are using "insertmember.php" in the form request and "Insertmember.php"in the file name.

Comment: There is `<? php` little space , remove that , also it should be like this `<?php` in your `insertmember.php`

Comment: You don't create any model page. Did you??

Comment: Here ->`echo$row['member_ID']` there must be little space between `echo` and `$row` also , you missed to add `;` at end , it should be like this -> `echo $row['member_ID'];`  , do the same for all other statements.

Comment: Thank you Marcelino, Sawti, the capitalization and the syntax is fixed, still seeing same issue when I try to access this page "http://localhost/firstwebapp/insertmember.php", is there something else I need to do/add?

Comment: Thanks Tahmid! I didn't do anything model page, is it like a file I also need to add in the model folder?

Comment: @obezzy915 Please post your `directory` structure .

Comment: Thanks and attached! (under the link "File structure")

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved.. I have to change
from:

```
form action = "insertmember.php" method ="post"
```

to:

```
form action = "index.php/welcome/insertmember" method ="post"
```

Thumbs up to Swati pointing me to the direction of checking my directory path